# Amazon MWS scratchpad access denied

Tags: api, amazon-mws

I am a registered PRO seller on Amazon UK (and all EU marketplaces on the same account)

I have my seller account ID, Developer Id, Developer Auth token and private key.

In MWS scratchpad, I can put a request and get a successful response for the status APIs as I don't believe they use any authetication, but any other request (e.g. listReports) just returns an access denied error message.  I know the credentials are correct as if I edit them, get get authentication error messages.  I have opened a case with support but after three days of waiting I have not even has acknowlegement of the issue let alone a solution.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or where I go in my admin panel to give my own developer account the correct permissions.

NOTE: This is not 3rd party development, I only want to build out solutions for my own business.

TIA

Aaron

Answer (score 5):

amazon scratchpad url is different country to country. most probably you are trying on different scratchpad country's url.